# Meta sites should be easier to distinguish in the iOS app when searching

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Screenshot]

The picture above is what I see when searching for the Personal Finance SE using 0.1.54 of the iOS app.

Since the name is so long, the word meta is not visible in the app and the color is the only way to distinguish. This is difficult for people that are colorblind or people like myself that just have no idea which is which.

The word "meta" should probably be first, not last when searching.

Comment: Another option is adding "Meta" watermark over the logo.

Comment: This will be implemented sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site listing now displays the full site name, so it's easier to distinguish 
between meta and non-meta sites.

This was fixed a while back.